# Keylogger for personal use that ONLY logs your last X characters

Tags: windows, windows-7, keylogger

I often times write things online and offline that end up getting lost either due to a session ending, the program crashing, or something else, and it's incredibly frustrating to have to rewrite everything you just wrote.

I don't need everything logged, nor old things, only what I've *just* written.  So, for privacy and safety reasons, I'm looking for a personal keylogger that will *only* log the last X characters that you typed and which allows you to customize that X variable.  Alternatively, although less effective, one that only recorded the last X minutes would also suffice.  So what I'm basically looking for is the Cockpit Voice Recorder of keyloggers.

Does such a keylogger exist?

Comment: Actually things are not that easy. You can write such a simple keylogger basically as a one-liner (with the help of some Nuget library). But you'll find the following issues: a) you'll switch between applications. Such a simple keylogger will just continue recording, e.g. a browser URL or Google search term which is not related to the text b) Some keys need special handling, e.g. the backspace key and the del key. c) copy & paste cannot detect the location where it is copied from and where it is inserted to d) consider any location change you did by mouse. The keylogger won't be able to follow

Comment: The result of above writing is: you'll switch between applications. The keya) loggerSuch a simple keylogger will just continue recording, e.g. a browser URL or googGle search term which is not relatesd to the text b) Some keys need special handling, e.g. the backspace key. c) Copyc & psaste will notcannot detect the location where it is copied from and where it is inserted to. and the arrow keys del keyAlso consider a d) consider any location change you did by mouse. The keylogger will notr be be able to knowon't be able to follow

Comment: Would that really be helpful or are you a far better typist?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [REFOG Free Keylogger](https://www.refog.com/):

- [free](http://www.refog.com/free.html)
- Windows
- log the last X characters that you typed
- allows you to customize that X variable:

[image]

Comment: Very interesting, thanks!  I've just installed it, but I don't see where I can customize the "last X characters" typed.  I can customize the Log size, but the minimum it allows is 1 MB and I don't know how many characters that is.  It won't accept anything under 1 MB.  Any ideas?

Comment: @ProgrammerGirl: 1MB is ~1 million keystrokes. More than you can probably type per day.